# Better CLI Tumblr tools

Tags: perl, bash, command-line-interface, tumblr

I am looking for the best tool in command line under linux, to interact with Tumblr.
I've found this https://github.com/ahoward/tumblr/ , but it's seems lite.
I'm not a big developper, I'm using bash and perl, so ...
And if possible, with OAuth
Thanks for your help !

Comment: "What's the best..." is [not a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) for StackOverflow

Comment: heu, why is not a good ? I don't want a benchmark, I'm looking for an existance, For exemple: nothing about OAuth it seems, only if developper have already do a lib/ a tool ...

Comment: Tumblr updated their API so I don't know if that CLI tool is of much use now

Answer (score 1):

A search on [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/) revealed the following modules:

- [`WWW::Tumblr`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW%3a%3aTumblr)
- [`WebService::Tumblr`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WebService%3a%3aTumblr)

Comment: Thanks ! (it seems the same thing in perl like tumblr.rb)